# Java 3D array assign values

Tags: java, arrays, 3d

I have an array that looks like this

```
static String[][][] School= new String[1000][20][5];
```

- In the first bracket I save the class name
- In the second I save an ID of a student
- In the third I save information about the student (his name, family name etc).

First I assign all the class names, after that I assign to every class its student ID and then I can fill in their information.

How can I do it? I tried it with for example

```
School[i] = "A1";
```

but it's not working.

EDIT: Or is there an other way to save this all 3 things? (class name, its students and its iformation)

Comment: Check this -  [Java program to add two three dimensional (3D) array.](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2013/02/java-program-to-add-two-three.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
static String[][][] School= new String[1000][20][5];
```

Consider figure which has 3 Dimension.

So when you insert `School[0][0][0]="A1"` it means you have entered element at 0,0,0 position.

From 0,0,0 this will move upto the position 1000,20,5.

You can insert like this But you have so many elements.

```
School[0][0][0]="A1"
School[0][0][1]="A2"
School[0][0][2]="A3"
.....
School[0][1][0]="B1"
School[0][1][1]="B2"
School[0][1][2]="B3"
......
```

In 3D array elements look like

```
int[3][4][2] array3D
// means Three (4x2) 2 Dimensional Arrays 

 int[4][2]
 //means Four 1 dimensional arrays.
```

---

*Now how to add elements in 3D array?*

At Start you can directly use

```
int[][][] threeDArray = 
    {  { {1,   2,  3}, { 4,  5,  6}, { 7,  8,  9} },
       { {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18} },
       { {19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27} } };
```

This is very tedious task in your case as you want to insert details at every position.
As you have `1000` records.

Your array will have elements like this

[image]

**NOTE**:*It's not recommended to use 3D array for this purpose.*

**Suggestion**:*Declare a class with three `Strings` create constructor with this three parameters and put getter and setters to get and set values via `Objects`*

Comment: Can you even declare the dimensions of the array like this `int[3][4][2] array3D` ? Or is that a mistake? If you can, then in which version or upto which version of java can you do this in?

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest instead of using a 3D array,  you shall create a `Student` Class that will hold all the information for a student and A Class for `SchoolClass` that will hold a list of students in the class and name of class and you can maintain an `Array of SchoolClass` to serve the purpose.

This way you will be able to manage it better.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your array won't do what you expect it to do.

Think of the array like a 3D array, with each element a point. If you specify a single index, you're essentially telling the computer "OK, I want to assign `"A1"` to *this slice of the array* (in your example, you're trying to do something akin to `String[][] elementAtI = "A1";`). Now that doesn't make sense, does it?

To get to a single element in the array, you have to specify all three indices, much like how in 3D space you have to specify all three coordinates to locate a point:

```
School[3][4][5] = "A1";
```

What might be a better idea than a 3D array is objects. Packing everything into an array works, but that's not as readable as having a `SchoolClass[]`, where each `SchoolClass` has a `name` and an array of `Students`, and each `Student` has an `ID`, `name`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, variable fields usually start with lowercase with camel text by convention.

```
static String[][][] school= new String[1000][20][5];
```

Secondly, arrays do not work like this. String[][][] holds {{{entry...}entry...}entry...}.
The entries may contain duplicates, which makes it an unfeasible method as you will get `{"3A", "1", "PersonName"}` and `{"3A", "1", "DifferentPersonName"}` within the same array. Each array dimension is holding additional dimensions, aka
`{"3A", {"1", {"PersonName"}, {"DifferentPersonName"}}}`, so

`School[i] = "A1";` is syntax error, because you must put String[][] in String[i][][]:

`School[i] = {{"A1","PersonName"}};`

I believe a solution here would be to use HashMaps. Repeated entries will overwrite each other. In this case, the code will be:

```
// The actual HashMap!
static final HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> school
=new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

/**
 * How to use an entry using the above HashSet:
 * 
 * @param className The name of the class.
 * @param id The id.
 * @param details The details.
 */
void addEntry(final String className, final String id, final String details){
  HashMap<String, String>value=school.get(className);
  // If the class already exists, use it, otherwise make new HashMap.
  (value==null ? value = new HashMap<String, String>() : value)
  // Here is how to put in the value mapping.
  .put(id, details);
  // Put it back in. This updates the entry.
  school.put(value);
}

/**
 * How to get (iterate through) entries from the above HashSet:
 * 
 * @return An array of students in format "class id details"
 */
String[] getStudentsSet(){
  // This is an iterator.
  Iterator<Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>>>iterator=
      school.entrySet().iterator();
  Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>>next;
  String now;
  // This is for testing
  final ArrayList<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();
  while(iterator.hasNext()){
    // Load new class name
    now=(next=iterator.next()).getKey();
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>>iteratorlv2=next.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
      final Entry<String, String>entry=iterator.next();
      /* This is the student from class "now", id "entry.getKey()", and details "entry.getValue()"
       * Change this line to what you want, or what you would like to use entries for.
       */
      final String student=now+" "+entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue();
      // This is for testing
      list.add(student);
    }
  }
  // This is what prints to the console so you know this thing works.
  for(final String o:list) System.out.println(o);
  return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```