# How can I add elements in a 3D array using loops in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I know how to add elements in a 2D array but for some reason, my 3d array isn't working am I doing it wrong?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++){

            for (int k = 1; k < IN; k++){
                myArray [i][j][k] = i + 10;
            }
        }

    }
```

I have my array like this myArray = new int [COLUMNS][ROWS][IN]; is that right? Because it should be like array = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

Comment: why does your k loop start at 1 and not 0 like the others?

Comment: What's wrong? provide more details, more code or explanation what happens?

Comment: @DM because I want the first element added to be a 1

Comment: @Piotrowy like am getting this as an output
{{0,10,10Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at ExerciseThree.printArrayStatement(ExerciseThree.java:117)
 at ExerciseOne.main(ExerciseOne.java:12)

Comment: `myArray = new int [COLUMNS][ROWS][IN];` - If this is your declaration, then `i` should probably go to `COLUMNS` and `j` should probably go to `ROWS`.

Comment: @C.Ikongo Problem is in your 'k' index. What do you want to do exactly with these loops?

Comment: Starting the k loop at 1 is weird but won't produce errors.  The columns and rows being reversed will.

Comment: @C.Ikongo if you have index out of bound it means your arrays initialization   does not correspond to for loops conditions. Give us full code

Comment: `int[][][] myStringArray = new int [ROWS][COLUMNS][IN];` – it should be your array declaration.

Comment: @C.Ikongo switch 'ROWS' and 'COLUMNS' in your for loops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 3D array assign values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630668/java-3d-array-assign-values)

Comment: @C.Ikongo I added answer which completes your exercise.

Comment: @Piotrowy Oh okay may I see how u did it?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your array: {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, then you shouldn't need a 3D array, only a 2D array.

The elements of the above array (which you provided) are:

```
myArray[0][0] // 1        myArray[0][1] // 2        myArray[0][2] // 3
myArray[1][0] // 4        myArray[1][1] // 5        myArray[1][2] // 6
myArray[2][0] // 7        myArray[2][1] // 8        myArray[2][2] // 9
```

Adjusting your code accordingly you get:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++){
        myArray[i][j] = i + 10;
    }
}
```

---

#### Doing this in 3D

If you have some 3D data to work with, you'll just add another dimension onto your current code. The array gets another dimension, we add another `[]`. The for loop gets another dimension, we add another nested loop.

Maybe we're keeping track of values in a 3D grid so we define our dimensions to be the size of the grid like this:

```
int rows = 3;
int columns = 4;
int layers = 5;
```

We declare our 3D array just like you said:

```
int[][][] my3dArray = new int[rows][columns][layers];
```

Then we can initialize those values and start using our array just like you started, only this time we're not going to reference the variables rows, and columns.

Instead, this time we're going to reference the length of the array. This makes our code more flexible. Another program/class could make a 3d array and send it to our program, and it would still work fine even though we didn't know in advance the size of their grid (like we did with ours).

```
for (int i = 0; i < my3dArray.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < my3dArray[0].length; j++) {

        for (int k = 0; k < my3dArray[0][0].length; k++) {

            // I randomly picked some formula
            my3dArray[i][j][k] = i + j * 100 + k * 10000;

    }

}
```

Comment: I see, I've added to my original answer and I think it may be what you're looking for. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not that different from creating an 2D array.

```
    // creating 3D array
    int[][][] myArray = new int[r][c][n];
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<c; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<n; k++){
                myArray[i][j][k] = i + 10;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630668/java-3d-array-assign-values/23631351#23631351)?
I hope this will help you with your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code with switched 'COLUMNS' and 'ROWS' in for loops and proper value assignment `i*10 + j + k*80;`

```
public static int [][][] myArray = new int[][][];
public static final int ROWS = 8, COLUMNS = 10, IN = 3;
public ExerciseThree() {
    myArray = new int [ROWS][COLUMNS][IN];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++){  
            for (int k = 0; k < IN; k++){
                myArray [i][j][k] = i*10 + j + k*80;
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Also you have mistakes in printing 3d array. You should switch you for loop condition from `<=` to `<` in 103 and 115 lines. But this way is better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
    System.out.print("{");
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++){
        System.out.print("{");  
        for (int k = 0; k < IN; k++){
            myArray [i][j][k] = i*10 + j + k*80;
            if (k < IN - 1) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("},");
    }
    System.out.print("},\n");
}
```

Comment: @C.Ikongo full answer here. you can mark this answer as correct one.