# Why is it saying illegal start of expression?

Tags: java, arrays

board is a 3D array that has already been declared. I am trying to directly assign it a value, but, attempting to do so gives me a host of errors.

```java
board[2][][] = {
    {10, 15, 19, 21, 22, 22, 21, 19, 15, 10},
    {15, 20, 24, 26, 27, 27, 26, 24, 20, 15},
    {19, 24, 28, 30, 31, 31, 30, 28, 24, 19},
    {21, 26, 30, 32, 33, 33, 32, 30, 26, 21},
    {22, 27, 31, 33, 34, 34, 33, 31, 27, 22},
    {22, 27, 31, 33, 34, 34, 33, 31, 27, 22},
    {21, 26, 30, 32, 33, 33, 32, 30, 26, 21},
    {19, 24, 28, 30, 31, 31, 30, 28, 24, 19},
    {15, 20, 24, 26, 27, 27, 26, 24, 20, 15},
    {10, 15, 19, 21, 22, 22, 21, 19, 15, 10}
};
```

[Errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIu3b.png)
I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: how does this data map as 3d array?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630668/java-3d-array-assign-values

Comment: Please add your errormessages to this question and do not link them (also do not provide them as image, just give us the error, perhaps in a quote- or code-block).

Comment: And I guess perhaps you want just ```board[2] = ...```, but I ain't sure

Comment: See also: [How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Islingre

I am assuming that the 3d board is defined in a similar fashion.

```
int board[][][] = new int[3][][];
```

Then  you can assign the 3rd element in the 1st dimension to have these other two dimensions.  Remembering of course that arrays are 0 based.

```
board[2] = new int[][] {
{10, 15, 19, 21, 22, 22, 21, 19, 15, 10},
{15, 20, 24, 26, 27, 27, 26, 24, 20, 15},
{19, 24, 28, 30, 31, 31, 30, 28, 24, 19},
{21, 26, 30, 32, 33, 33, 32, 30, 26, 21},
{22, 27, 31, 33, 34, 34, 33, 31, 27, 22},
{22, 27, 31, 33, 34, 34, 33, 31, 27, 22},
{21, 26, 30, 32, 33, 33, 32, 30, 26, 21},
{19, 24, 28, 30, 31, 31, 30, 28, 24, 19},
{15, 20, 24, 26, 27, 27, 26, 24, 20, 15},
{10, 15, 19, 21, 22, 22, 21, 19, 15, 10}
};
```